# Preselect drop down option based on the onclick table value and navigate to another page

Tags: python, html, jquery, mysql, flask

I want to pre-select the dropdown option based on the onclick table value, while navigate to another page of dropdown option.

Below is the code

app.py

```
@app.route('/userinfo',methods=["POST","GET"])
def userinfo():
    result = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id")
    user= cursor.fetchall()
    result1 = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM header ORDER BY id ")
    header = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('userinfo.html', user= user, result1=result1)
```

userinfo.html

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="cols-sm-10">
        <h5>user onfo </h5>
          <select name="name1" class="teamForm" id="teamDropdown" type="text" placeholder="Select projects">
            {% for i in user %}
                <option id="{{ i.id }}" value= "{{ i.id }}">{{ i.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
          <select name="tasks" class="teamForm2" id="teamDropdown1" type="text" method="POST">
            {% for j in header %}
            <option id="{{ j.id }}" value= "{{ j.header1 }}" selected>{{j.header1 }}</option>
            <option id="{{ j.id }}" value= "{{ j.header2 }}">{{j.header2 }}</option>
            <option id="{{ j.id }}" value= "{{ j.header3 }}" selected>{{j.header3 }}</option>
            <option id="{{ j.id }}" value= "{{ j.header4 }}" selected>{{j.header4 }}</option>                
            {% endfor %}                  
          </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

index.html

```
<thead>
  {% for row in header %}
   <tr>
      <th data-pk="{{row.id}}">{{row.id}}</th>
      <th data-pk={{row.id}}">{{row.name}}</th>
      <th data-pk="{{row.id}}">{{row.date}}</th>
      <th data-pk="{{row.id}}">{{row.header1}}</th>
      <th data-pk="{{row.id}}">{{row.header2}}</th>
      <th data-pk="{{row.id}}">{{row.header3}}</th>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
 </thead>
<tbody>
{% for row in emp %}
<tr>
  <td data-pk="{{row.id}}">{{row.id}}</td>
  <td data-name="name" class="name" data-type="text" data-pk="{{row.id}}">{{row.name}}</td>
  <td class="under-limit" onclick="location.href='/userinfo'">{{row.task1}}</td>
  <td class="under-limit" onclick="location.href='/userinfo'">{{row.task2}}</td>
  <td class="under-limit" onclick="location.href='/userinfo'">{{row.task3}}</td>
</tr>
 {% endfor %}
{/tbody>
```

When i click on the table cell, based on the row and column selected, dropdown option has to be selected, while navigate to another page. I tried to do with Jquery but i couldnt do it. Please can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution.

```
$('.under-limit').on('click', function(id) {
let $cell = $(this);
let txt = $cell.text();
var cellIndex = $cell.index()-1;
var header = $cell.closest('table').find('th').eq($cell.index()-2).text();
alert(txt + ':' + header);
```

pass the header value with the window.location.href which navigates to anther page.

From the above code remove in the onclick event